# How to configure speaking URL of tx_blog extension in TYPO3 9.x

Tags: typo3, yaml, extbase, realurl

I am looking for the configuration YAML for TYPO3 tx_blog extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext:blog` come up with enhancing routing feature itself. It will give you basic YAML configuration below path:

```
'EXT:blog/Configuration/Routes/Default.yaml'
```

You just need to import these settings, use below code in your routing YAML configuration.

```
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:blog/Configuration/Routes/Default.yaml" }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, Ghanshyam its works perfect. and here (EXT:blog/Configuration/Routes/) we got all the blog plugin's configuration. https://prnt.sc/olw978

Comment: Great @Sonal! Keep coding!